# Align a part of shape to an axis (Inkscape)

Tags: inkscape

I have none aligned shape and want to rotate it so a part of it aligns to X or Y axis so I could work easier with it. Here is a simplified version:

[image]

is there any quick and easy method to this? any snapping options?
I don't want to align it by eye because it's a big shape and I don't want it to be off even by an small amount so rotating by eye is out of question in here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put a horizontal guide (not a path, but guide, a straight path can be converted to guide if needed) to the uppermost corner of your white rectangle-like branch. Move the rotation center to the same point and rotate manually with snaps to all kinds of nodes and rotation center =ON.

[image]

Nodes will snap to the guide when you rotate manually. Other items than guides do not catch nodes during rotation. Drag a horizontal guide down from the horizontal ruler, there's no need to convert a line to guide.